# mySQL error: Table 'table' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql

Out of the sudden I am getting a weird error on my mysql database tables.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

returns:

```
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine
```

I can confirm that the tables do indeed exist on local file system and `show tables;` does indeed return the tables I am interested in.

```
show tables;

+-----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb  |
+-----------------+
| presets         |
| mytable           |
+-----------------+
```

And the select:

```
select * from mytable;

Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine.
```

Error makes absolute no sense and I've been working with this tables a couple of days ago without any problems. I haven't moved the tables. What should I do?

Before that error above showed up I was getting an error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES),
```

but I successfully updated the password. I have no idea what triggered this error because I haven't played with passwords. However, when I tried to fix this error I have set permissions on `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` to `read/write` to everyone.

```
UPDATE:

show table status gives back a really weird outout:

    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
    | Name            | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment                                              |
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
    | preset          | NULL   |    NULL | NULL       | NULL |           NULL |        NULL |            NULL |         NULL |      NULL |           NULL | NULL                | NULL        | NULL       | NULL              |     NULL | NULL           | Table 'mydb.preset' doesn't exist in engine          |
    | mytable         | NULL   |    NULL | NULL       | NULL |           NULL |        NULL |            NULL |         NULL |      NULL |           NULL | NULL                | NULL        | NULL       | NULL              |     NULL | NULL           | Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine         |
```

Comment: Show us the code or the exact query you're running. Also: Have you selected a database? ie. `USE \`dbname\``

Comment: just the most simple select * from table, where table is the name of the table.  I have used `USE`before querying.

Answer (score 1):

The `SHOW TABLES` result looks a little off. The box has a bit more space on the `mytable` line. Is it possible there's an invisible character in your tablename somehow? Maybe you created it wrong?

Comment: Ahh, that was an error in my head, when I was typing the question. Sorry about that. I edited the question with query and the direct response from mySQL

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: no, I am just using replacement for my table names. I've been doing sql for years. This is not a syntax error

Comment: I didn't mean syntax error. The extra spacing in the table might indicate that there's a weird unicode character in the name

Comment: Did you manually change database names by moving files? Or did you migrate to a new server?

Comment: nothing.  just some day everything stopped working. I've got an entire backend tied to mysql database that just stopped working. I've been developing the backend for quite some time now this database and tables have been operational so far. Until it just broke. Once again, this has nothing to do with table names. All table names are correct and if there is an extra space in the question, that is solely because I gave tables  a different name, here, in SO question.